# iFlyTek, Spark Embeddings Error Code - 11202

Tags: python, langchain, embedding

I followed, below langchain documentation

**Reference** - https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/text_embedding/sparkllm

**Error Details**:
Request error: 11202, {'header': {'code': 11202, 'message': 'licc failed', 'sid': 'ase000fd997@dx18e35059f4c738d882'}}